# PyQt: Initialize default values for reset

Tags: python, pyqt, initialization, pyqt4, default

I have a `MainUI`, that has a few buttons, line-edits and checkboxes. Most of the widgets I have set with a given state - e.g. all checkboxes are checked by default, and all line-edit fields have a default value of "1.0".

Currently I have a pushbutton called "reset everything". As its name implies, any changes made in these checkboxes or line-edit fields will be reverted to be checked and have a value of "1.0".

One way I can think of resetting the values, is by creating a function where I have to re-type the variable names of the affected widgets, along with their default state - which is similar to what I did when I created them. But I don't think this is a practical method.

My question here is: what is the best way for me to store the default values and then revert them?

So far I have created a class that contains the creation of the main ui:

```
class MainUI(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setWindowTitle('UI MANAGER')
        self.setModal(False)
        self.init_main_ui()
        self.resize(QtCore.QSize(600, 350))

    # UI-Configurations
    def init_main_ui(self):
        self.check1 = QtGui.QCheckBox("chk_box1")
        self.check2 = QtGui.QCheckBox("chk_box2")
        self.check3 = QtGui.QCheckBox("chk_box3")
        self.check1.setChecked(True)
        self.check2.setChecked(True)
        self.check3.setChecked(True)
        self.max_label = QtGui.QLabel("MIN Val")
        self.max_input = QtGui.QLineEdit("0.0")
        self.min_label = QtGui.QLabel("MAX Val")
        self.min_input = QtGui.QLineEdit("1.0")
        ...
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach would be to refactor your existing code so that the initial values are set by a separate method:

```
class MainUI(QtGui.QDialog):
    ...

    def init_main_ui(self):
        self.check1 = QtGui.QCheckBox("chk_box1")
        self.check2 = QtGui.QCheckBox("chk_box2")
        self.check3 = QtGui.QCheckBox("chk_box3")
        self.max_label = QtGui.QLabel("MIN Val")
        self.max_input = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.min_label = QtGui.QLabel("MAX Val")
        self.min_input = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        ...
        self.reset_main_ui()        

    def reset_main_ui(self):
        self.check1.setChecked(True)
        self.check2.setChecked(True)
        self.check3.setChecked(True)
        self.max_input.setText("0.0")
        self.min_input.setText("1.0")
        ...
```